# Using SharePoint via Office Hub on Windows Phone 7

Tags: authentication, mobile

What settings are required to connect to SharePoint via the Office Hub on Windows Phone 7?  I've heard so many contradictory things that I have no idea what it takes.  Is it using claims auth? classic auth, while on an intranet?

Comment: Where is your SharePoint environment?  Is it internally hosted, SharePoint Online, hosted online somewhere else?

Comment: Corporate 2007 environment, Dev 2010 environment. Looking at using hosted sharepoint 2010 implementation, but need to know what works with the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the web application needs to support anonymous or forms-based authentication (which requires claims), because Windows Phone 7 does not support Windows authentication. I think you can also use Basic authentication but wouldn't recommend it.

There are ways to implement FBA so that the credentials map to AD using an LDAP authentication provider.

The Microsoft recommended solution, for an intranet situation, is to use Forefront UAG if possible. This translates from FBA to Windows so you don't need to do a lot of work on your SharePoint configuration. But of course you have to implement (and pay for) UAG.

This may well all change with the Mango release in late 2011. I think a lot of people will be waiting for an update to WP7 to support Windows authentication rather than try to get it working.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll set this up in my dev environment and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: There are some caveats to this. First, NTLM works fine for domain names without dots in them. Fully qualified domain names fail, but the old netbios style names work because WP7 trusts them. Also, there are reported cases of claims working without FBA. See Jason Taraby's response in this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/sharepoint-doesnt-support-this-authentication/5ba8116a-6955-4486-b19e-c93affa346a8?page=4&tab=AllReplies

Comment: No, sorry, NTLM authentication is not (yet) available on Windows Phone 7 for accessing web services or the Office Hub. And to those people down-voting me - please don't shoot the messenger! Tom, you can access SharePoint using NTLM from the browser using NetBIOS-style domain names (which IE assumes are trusted), but not the Office Hub.